# Programmatically set IP configuration persistently on headless?

Tags: ethernet, static-ip, systemd-networkd

Apologies for the tortured title but I'll explain the question more clearly:

We have a headless Pi compute module (CM4) which needs to be remotely configurable, and that includes being able to send it a command to configure a static IP address, gateway, netmask, etc. (or set it to DHCP) **and have this setting persist across reboots.**

I've done this before in various embedded Linuxes and there seems to be several ways of doing it depending on [when the StackOverflow question was last asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652384/how-to-set-the-ip-address-from-c-in-linux) and which specific Linux flavour you're using... so I am here asking what's the right way of doing this in 2022 on a CM4 running the latest Raspbian?

Ideally something doable / callable from within standard C code.

EDIT: **No, we cannot just do this from the DHCP server** as there's no guarantee there IS one in any given installation or that it's configurable, it's an operational requirement of THIS hardware that it can be set to a static IP configuration regardless of the network it's currently plugged into.

Comment: Assuming you're using `dhcpcd`: Have you tried?: **Create two `dhcpcd.conf` files in `etc` (e.g `dhcpcd.static.conf`, and `dhcpcd.dynamic.conf`), and then do a `mv dhcpcd.dynamic.conf dhcpcd.conf` to "swap" to the one you want**. Afterwards, you'll need to tell `dhcpcd` to re-read its `dhcpcd.conf` file.

Comment: @Seamus if by "using" you mean "whatever Raspbian uses by default" then yes, I'd suggest it's dhcpcd - I've seen the method of re-writing / generating a dhcpcd.conf file but wasn't sure if that is the "right" or most compatible / nicest way of doing it compared to (say) calling `ip` with popen() or something.

Comment: RE "using": I had to ask because the Rpi org has decided to replace `dhcpcd` in the not-distant future, and of course some are moving already. Personally, I feel `dhcpcd` is the better choice, but... Anyway - yes, write one conf file for using dynamic address assignment, and another for static - if you feel you need a static config at all.

Comment: It's easiest to do this on your ROUTER. Assign an IP address to your MAC address and your Raspberry can run dhcpcd as normal but will get a fixed IP address.

Comment: @Dougie that's not the question being asked - the customer wants to be able to configure THIS device to have a fixed IP whenever & wherever you plug it in. This is not a debate about why you'd want to do that, it's an operational requirement we have to meet.

Comment: The problem with "fixed IP whenever and whereever" is there's too many combinations. You can't assume everything uses 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x. There's also the 172.[16-31].x.x and 10.x.x.x networks to consider. Setting a fixed address on the router makes most sense. Setting it on the RPi makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Dougie you are missing the point - the device/equipment gets installed and ONE OPTION the customer *requires* of it is that they can configure it to have a static IP, there's no argument/discussion about whether this is a good idea or not or whether other ways are "better". If they want to configure it badly or incorrectly that's their problem.